# Why does console.log trigger ngDoCheck?

Tags: angular

Why does `console.log` trigger `ngDoCheck`? This kind of behavior makes me very confused; it is too frequent.

```
import { Component, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements DoCheck  {
  name = 'Angular';
  constructor(){
     interval(1000).subscribe(console.log)
  }

  ngDoCheck(){
    console.log('do check')
  }
}
```

Here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kvwddd

Comment: because angular cannot decide if any changes made during `interval(1000).subscribe(console.log)`, so angular has to doCheck to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**rxjs** `interval` operator uses `setInterval` method under the hood.

The `setInterval` method is patched by zonejs and on each callback Angular runs change detection because that is how Angular works. And on every change detection ngDoCheck will be called.

So it would be correct to ask: 
Why **rxjs** interval triggers Angular change detection?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [yurzui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5485167/yurzui) has reason. I would just like to add that if maybe you want to avoid that behavior, you can run the interval or any other asynchronous task inside an ngZone, look:

```
import { Component, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements DoCheck {
  name = 'Angular';
  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {
    ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      interval(1000).subscribe(console.log);
    });
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    console.log('do check');
  }
}
```